# Можно ли создать data class на C++?

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

В языке `Kotlin` можно создавать простые классы с помощью `data class`:

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

При этом для объектов автоматически генерируется код для:

1. Перевода в `data class` строку: `"User(name=John, age=42)"`.
2. Сравнение и
3. копирование дата классов.

Можно ли что-то подобное сделать на `C++` с помощью макросов и/или вариативных шаблонов?

Возможный пример того как это должно работать:

```
DataClass(Data, string, name, int, age);
// ...
Data d = { "Mike", 33 };
d.name = "John";
d.age = 42;
cout << d; // Data(name=John, age=42)
```

Comment: С помощью макросов можно сделать что угодно :D

Comment: @Qwertiy, настоящую рекурсию, например, нельзя :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая старая-старая технология - x-macro. Но это очень темная магия. Вот Вам заготовка, которая в принципе все делает, дорабатывайте по необходимости

```
#define X_AIR_DATACLASS  \
X(int, Crew) \
X(int, SeatingCapacity) \
X(int, Payload) \
X(int, Range) \
X(int, TopSpeed) \
X(int, CargoCapacity) \
X(int, FuelCapacity) \
X(int, Engines) \
X(int, Altitude) \
X(double, mach) \
X(double, Wingspan)


typedef struct {
#define X(type, name) type name;

    X_AIR_DATACLASS
#undef X
}Public_Airplane;


void print (Public_Airplane x)
{
    #define X(type, name) << #name": " << x.name << ", "
    std::cout << "(" X_AIR_DATACLASS << ")";
    #undef X
}

bool compare(Public_Airplane x, Public_Airplane y)
{
    #define X(type, name) x.name == y.name &&
    return X_AIR_DATACLASS 1;
    #undef X
}
```

Comment: Сейчас все упирается в то, что нельзя использовать макросы внутри другого макроса.

Comment: Можно использовать макросы внутри макроса. Вот определить макрос внутри макроса....

Comment: * определять макросы

Comment: а есть ли какие-нибудь сторонние "препроцессоры"? Например, я пишу код специального вида внутри комментария, а этот "препроцессор" потом преобразует закомментированный код в код `C++`. Что-то типа компиляции `coffescript -> javascript`.

Comment: да, есть. Например, [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html). Но на самом то деле никто не мешает написать свой - так поступили ребята с Qt.

Comment: спасибо. Для меня это будет лучшим решением.

Answer (score 0):

Откровенно говоря, не вижу, чем это хуже:

```
struct Data
{
    string name;
    int age;
};
Data d = { "Mike", 33 };
d.name = "John";
d.age = 42;
cout << d.name;
```

Если нужно - нет вопросов дописать оператор `<<` для вывода в любом требуемом виде...

Если очень хочется - можно поиграться и с препроцессором, но смысл? Экономия на стучании по клавишам будет минимальной, зато программа станет совершенно непонятной как постороннему, так, в общем-то, и пишущему... Тем более что потом может оказаться, что проверку на равенство лучше выполнять не так, и выводить не в том виде - и что? переписывать с нуля?

Или это тот момент, который часто встречается у изучающих C/C++ - с помощью макросов превратить его в более родной. Ну, типа, делать Паскаль с помощью

```
#define begin   {
#define end     }
```

Но это идея очень нездоровая...

Comment: Писать повторяющийся код тоже как-то не очень.

Comment: @SergeyPestov какой именно код Вы считаете повторяющимся?

Comment: @alexolut, код оператора сравнения и оператора вывода будет везде одинаков с точность до названия и количества переменных.